# Linker errors when statically linking libcurl+openssl to my project

Tags: c++, curl, openssl, mingw, libcurl

I am trying to statically link [libcurl](http://www.gknw.net/mirror/curl/win32/curl-7.21.7-devel-mingw32.zip) (with SSL) into my project, but I am encountering lots of linker errors:

```
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa9c): undefined reference to `CreateDCA@16'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xaa9): undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleDC@4'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xaba): undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xaca): undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xae0): undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleBitmap@12'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xaee): undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb00): undefined reference to `GetObjectA@12'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb71): undefined reference to `BitBlt@36'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xb7b): undefined reference to `GetBitmapBits@12'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xbd2): undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xbd9): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xbe3): undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
../lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xbed): undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
../lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x1b3b): undefined reference to `inet_addr@4'
../lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x1ba4): undefined reference to `inet_addr@4'
../lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x5d1e): undefined reference to `htonl@4'
../lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x5eed): undefined reference to `ntohl@4'
../lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x6f9a): undefined reference to `htonl@4'
../lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x728d): undefined reference to `htonl@4'
../lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x732c): undefined reference to `htonl@4'
../lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0x757f): undefined reference to `ntohl@4'
../lib/librtmp.a(rtmp.o):rtmp.c:(.text+0xb45): undefined reference to `timeGetTime@0'
```

Here is the list of files in lib folfer that I downloaded. [image]

I was told that I should define the macro `CURL_STATICLIB` and link in `wsock32` and `wldap32`. Is there anything else that I should be doing?

I am using MinGW and Eclipse.

```
g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB -DUSE_LIBSSH2 -DHAVE_LIBSSH2 -DCURL_DISABLE_LDAP -DHAVE_LIBSSH2_H -DLIBSSH2_WIN32 -DLIBSSH2_LIBRARY -DUSE_SSLEAY -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\CURLDown.o ..\src\CURLDown.cpp

g++ -L../lib -oCURLDown.exe src\CURLDown.o -lcurl -lcrypto -lwsock32 -lwldap32 -leay32 -lidn -lrtmp -lssh2 -lz -lssl32 -lssl
```

Comment: Undefined reference to _what_? This question is far too vague to answer.

Comment: A lot of. from url.o, from rtmp.o and many others. I just can't understand, if they provide libraries, why it can't be a simple manual, I tried to include all libs from there, just some of them I know I really need - libcurl.a and libeay32.a, libssleay32.a and libz.a. In every case I get some different undefined reference to errors

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: [here is described problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013708/weird-things-with-libcurl-and-openssl) when I comliled it myself, I did the same, in couple of minutes whill show errors when I used downloaded libs.

Comment: Stop. Step back, take a breath, and spend some time formulating a neat, high-quality question with all the pertinent information. That's the way to get good answers. There are plenty of examples of high-quality questions on SO.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I have updated the question

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013708/weird-things-with-libcurl-and-openssl) as for me is good, describes all steps that I also did. As for this question - I simply downloaded libs and included them into project, you can see in pastebin with what flags it is compiled.

Comment: I edited your question to increase its quality. Hopefully you will get some answers now! BTW, did you try the libcurl mailing list?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: yes, I wrote to them today. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

For those searching for this answer on google - the `` undefined reference to `CreateDCA@16' `` linker error is looking for libgdi.a (just -lgdi would do).  Bear in mind it has to be included *after* libcurl and openssl in the list of libraries to link.

Answer (score 0):

g++ -L../lib -oCURLDown.exe src\CURLDown.o -lcurl -leay32 -lidn -lrtmp -lssh2 -lz -lssl32 -lcrypto

suggests that you really don't specify all libs. Maybe there is a typo in your makefile?
I also see a reference to timeGetTime() which resides in Winmm.lib.

Also libeay32 and libcrypto seem to have a misunderstanding in who should define what. There is probably accidently a sourcefile that is compiled by both libs that should only be compiled by one.