# Sending http and https requests from C/C++

Tags: c++, google-api

Is there any other variants to send http/https request from C/C++ except using libCurl? I can't figure out how to use libCurl with OpenSSL :( I want to interact with YoutubeAPI.

Comment: Just because you "can't figure [out] how to use libcurl with OpenSSL" doesn't change that it's _the_ way to do this. Instead of giving up and looking for an alternative, find out what the problem is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) has a nice, simple to use in-built HTTP implementation. You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/network-http.php). It looks to me that for youtube you can simply use POST - look [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authentication.html#Authentication).

Comment: Yep, just post, but pure C++ cant send post request, ot I don't khow how?

Comment: SFML can - I used it once to retrieve xml's from the EVE Online API - It worked great. You just use `SendRequest`. I can give you a code example if you want

Comment: Yep, well at least I think so. I did EVE requests to `https://api.eveonline.com/account/characters.xml.aspx?userID=#####&apiKey=#########` and it worked fine

Comment: HTTPS protocol is not supported by sf::Http.
See code here: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Network/Http.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps these two examples will be of help to you?

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplessl.html

Comment: no, I understand how to use libcurl functions. I can't figure out how to connect libcurl with OpenSSL to my project. When I built myself libcurl with OpelSSL, project compiled without errors, but dont run, it's just terminated without messages. Or when I tried to use already comliled libs - [here what I get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999086/static-linking-libcurl-with-openssl)

Comment: @Country: If you now want to know why your libcurl attempts did not work, then _that is a new question_ (and probably the one you should have asked in the first place!).

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: [I've asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999086/static-linking-libcurl-with-openssl). Noone answers

Comment: @Country: The question was of poor quality and can be improved. That is _certainly_ not a reason to give up on libcurl, which is the right tool for the job.

Comment: have the same problem with libcurl, it's just crushes. I think it's related to my x64 machine....

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say on which platform.

On windows there is also the WinInet-API which handles ssl transparently and uses the windows-built-in-certificates:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384233%28VS.85%29.aspx

libcurl is imho a much friendlier API though.

Answer (score 0):

there are alot of c++ libs out there to do that, anyways I agree that libCurl is one of the easiest and most lighweight solutions, and thus i'd recommend using it. If you want to look for an alternative anyways you might want to check out poco: http://pocoproject.org/